# how to identify the method name that calling the particular function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to change the subject of  mail according to actions(create, update), that call the mailer. How to do this? (ex. during creation, subject is User created and for update , user updated)

```
def create
@user = User.new(params[:user])
@user.save
Mailer.notify(@user).deliver 
end
def update
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@user.update
Mailer.notify(@user).deliver
end
```

mailers.rb

```
def notify(user)
@user =user
mail(:to =>@use.mail  :subject => "created")
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# controller
def create
  @user = User.create(params[:user])
  Mailer.notify(@user, 'created').deliver 
end

def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.update
  Mailer.notify(@user, 'updated').deliver
end

# mailers.rb
def notify(user, action_name)
  @user = user
  mail(:to => @user.mail, :subject => "User #{action_name}")
end
```

Comment: I think It will be more obviously, to pass action name as second parameter +1

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name of the calling method by using

```
caller_locations(1)[0].label
```

Example:

```
def bar
  caller_locations(1)[0].label
end

def foo
  bar
end

foo # => "foo"
```